# remote tmp directory not set for ansible script execution

Tags: ansible

I need to install binary on remote servers. Following are the list of tasks that i am performing.

1. Copy/scp binary to remote server
2. Run the installer in silent mode

Step #1 is copying binaries to `/tmp`, on remote hosts `/tmp` has very less space and scp is failing once the `/tmp` is full. I understood that by default ansible scripts/files will be copied to `/tmp` directory, once the activity is done it will be removed. Since `/tmp` is very low i need to use user directory to copy the binaries.

Below is `ansible.cfg`:

```
remote_user = testaccount
host_key_checking = False
scp_if_ssh=True
remote_tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
```

Below is the playbook:

```
- name: deploy binaries
  hosts: test
  strategy: free
  become_method: 'sudo'
  tasks:
    - name: transfer
      copy: src=./files/weblogic.jar dest=$HOME mode=0777
      register: transfer
    - debug: var=transfer.stdout
```

playbook execution:

```
ansible-playbook --inventory="hosts" --ask-pass --ask-become-pass --extra-vars="ansible_ssh_user=<unixaccount>" copybinaries.yml
```

Even with above config the binaries are not copied to user home, I have make sure to have `$HOME/.ansible/tmp` directory and even hard coded like `/home/testaccount/.ansbile/tmp`.

Any other configs needs to be overridden in `ansible.cfg`?

Comment: I still can't see where you actually use `become`, nor which user you become. On top of that `remote_user = testaccount` and `ansible_ssh_user=<unixaccount>` might be contradictory. At least they are confusing in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you still have not included a coherent [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I guess:

- either you are running the task with become-an-unprivileged-user option;
- or your inventory file, configuration file, the execution call, and the playbook contain unnecessary and contradictory settings making Ansible run in a more or less nondeterministic way.

---

Ansible uses the system temp directory for tasks being run as a different user. [This line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L216) determines this.

You can only specify `/tmp` (default) or a subdirectory of `/var/tmp` for such tasks (with `remote_tmp`). See [the comment](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/lib/ansible/plugins/shell/__init__.py#L097) in the Ansible code:

```
# When system is specified we have to create this in a directory where
# other users can read and access the temp directory.  This is because
# we use system to create tmp dirs for unprivileged users who are
# sudo'ing to a second unprivileged user.  The only dirctories where
# that is standard are the tmp dirs, /tmp and /var/tmp.  So we only
# allow one of those two locations if system=True.  However, users
# might want to have some say over which of /tmp or /var/tmp is used
# (because /tmp may be a tmpfs and want to conserve RAM or persist the
# tmp files beyond a reboot.  So we check if the user set REMOTE_TMP
# to somewhere in or below /var/tmp and if so use /var/tmp.  If
# anything else we use /tmp (because /tmp is specified by POSIX nad
# /var/tmp is not).
```

Comment: Yes. We need to run playbooks using sudo account. Can we still have customize tmp directory for running playbooks using sudo login ?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can only choose `/var/tmp` or modify the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have setup tmp as "var/tmp" in ansible.cfg. Able to transfer files now.